# Resultant of two polynomials in $K[X,Y]$ is a polynomial in $K[X]$ with degree less than the product of the original ones

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $f, g$ be two polynomials in $K[X,Y]$ with $K$ a field and consider them as polynomials in one indeterminate with coefficientes in$ K[X]$, ie, as elements of $K[X][Y]$, then the resultant of these two polynomials would be another polynomial $d \in K[X]$ and I want to show that $\operatorname{deg}(d) \leq \operatorname{deg}(f)\operatorname{deg}(g)$.

I found it in a textbook on algebraic geometry as part of some proof but there is no hint or reference on how to prove it and I have no idea on how to get the result.

Could someone give a proof about this result?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean resultant? Usually one takes the discriminant of a single polynomial, not multiple polynomials. If you do, you ought to be able to derive this from looking at the definition of the resultant via the Sylvester matrix.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I mean the resultant sorry, I'm going to change it, but I cannot derive it from the definition :/

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, when you say $\deg f$, which degree do you mean? The degree in $y$, in $x$, or the total degree?

Comment: @KReiser The total degree

Comment: When you get a chance, please do consider giving my answer below a gander.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $f$ and $g$ as polynomials in $y$ as follows:

$$f= a_0y^d+a_1y^{d-1}+\cdots+a_d$$
$$g= b_0y^e+b_1y^{e-1}+\cdots+b_e.$$

Then the resultant of these two polynomials is given by the determinant of the Sylvester matrix. Here's an example when $f$ has degree three in $y$ and $g$ has degree two in $y$:

$$S=
\begin{pmatrix} a_0 & & b_0 & & \\
 a_1 & a_0 & b_1 & b_0 & \\
 a_2 & a_1 & b_2 & b_1 & b_0 \\
 a_3 & a_2 & & b_2 & b_1 \\
 & a_3 & & & b_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now recall that $\renewcommand{\s}{\sigma}\det S = \sum_{\s\in S_{d+e}} |\s|\prod s_{i\s(i)}$. I claim that when $s_{ij}\neq 0$, $\deg_x s_{ij} \leq \deg(f)-d+i-j$ or $\deg_x s_{ij} \leq \deg(g)-e+i-j+e=\deg(g)+i-j$ depending on whether $j\leq e$ or not. Therefore $$\deg_x \prod s_{i\s(i)} \leq e(\deg(f)-d)+d(\deg(g)) + \sum i-\s(i).$$ As $\sum i-\s(i) =0$ and $e(\deg(f)-d) + d(\deg(g)) \leq \deg(f)\deg(g)$, we have the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Let $f=x^2y^3+7xy^5+17$ and $g=x^5+6x+5y^2x-1$. Then the resultant is given by
$$
{\rm Res}(f,g,y)=49x^{27} - 70x^{24} + 1470x^{23} - 245x^{22} + 25x^{21} - 1680x^{20} + 17920x^{19} - 5880x^{18}
 + 940x^{17} - 15195x^{16} + 110880x^{15} - 53340x^{14} + 11520x^{13} - 61870x^{12} + 347835x^{11} - 216720x^{10} + 58600x^9 - 99300x^8 + 442199x^7 - 332665x^6 + 1010645x^5 -
17710x^4 + 1470x^3 - 49x^2.
$$
So we see that the degree is less than $\deg(f)\deg(g)=6\cdot 5=30$.
Since the resultant is a determinant polynomial coming from the Sylvester matrix, the estimate follows from it, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

Comment: I know all of that, but I cannot see how to proof the estimate in general.